# How are answers ranked on SO?

Tags: discussion, answers

Just as in Google, the ranking of the answers has a great impact on how likely they are to be read. Since I'm interested in building a reputation, I want my answers to sit at the top so that they get addressed and rewarded first.

I don't know how this ranking works and I would like to know. It seems like it might just be votes, then, who answered first, but I've seen my position change due to edits sometimes when we have the same number of votes.

Answer (score 5):

Next to the heading where it says the number of answers is a set of tabs for sorting answers according to different criteria. The default is "votes". The reason you may see your answer switch around randomly when sorting by votes is because that tab sorts by votes alone — if two or more answers have the same score, they are sorted randomly across page loads.